# watching ng-repeat objects used outside of of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, intervals, watch

Ok I have created a ng-repeat to get all users created by an $http.get. This get request updates every 5 secs by using $interval and displays individual user data when clicked by calling $scope.goInfo(data). This $scope.goInfo(data) is used throughout the page to show user data, but is created by the ng-repeat (but not always used in ng-repeat). How can I have this data obj created by ng-repeat update every 5 secs outside of ng-repeat? I can't wrap $scope.goInfo() in a $interval.

EXAMPLE

```
//CONTROLLER//
function liveFeed(){
    $http.get('some URL').then(function (user) {
        $scope.user = user.data;
        console.log('user data is', $scope.user);
    });
}

//Updates get req every five secs//
$interval(liveFeed, 5000);             

//gets data obj from ng-repeat, needs to be updated every 5 secs.//
$scope.goInfo = function (data) {       
    $scope.name = data.name;
    $scope.beats = data.beats;
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
   <th>First Name: John</th>
   <th>Last Name:</th>
      <tr ng-repeat="data in user" ng-click = "goInfo(data)">
         <td>{{data.name}}<td>
      </tr>
</table>

<span>{{beats}}</span><!--needs to update every 5 secs, outside of ng-repeat and be binded to the user that was clicked on-->
```

Comment: Maybe the same http request but this time instead of using ngRepeat directive, use angular.forEach to iterate throught response.data and find name and beats.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset selected object after you retrieve new data. Basically, you just need to find corresponding records in new array of objects and set it as selected again.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
function liveFeed() {
    $http.get('some URL').then(function(user) {
        $scope.user = user.data;

        // Find the record that was selected before this update
        if ($scope.selectedUser) {
            $scope.selectedUser = $scope.user.filter(function(obj) {
                return obj.name === $scope.selectedUser.name; // or compare by unique id
            })[0];
        }
    });
}

// Updates get req every five secs
$interval(liveFeed, 5000);

// Gets data obj from ng-repeat, needs to be updated every 5 secs
$scope.goInfo = function(data) {
    $scope.selectedUser = data;
}
```

and HTML will use `selectedUser`:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name: John</th>
        <th>Beats:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in user" ng-click="goInfo(data)">
        <td>{{data.name}}<td>
        <td>{{data.beats}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<span>{{selectedUser.beats}}</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, i see how this a working but for some reason the {{selectedUser.beats}} still isn't updating live when my backend changes once a user is selected. Am I doing something wrong ???